# Can you git clone with ssh from Azure Devops Server repos?

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops, git-clone, azure-devops-server-2019

I would like to authenticate using SSH when git cloning repos from our Azure Devops Server (hosted onpremises).

I do see a tutorial in [Microsoft's docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=current-page), however the sample seems to be for Azure Devops Services (hosted in cloud).

Moreover - in the "git clone" section I see the SSH tab with no URL filled.

[image]

Is it possible? Is our Devops Server missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable SSH on your server. In the management console, select Application Tier and in the right side you'll find the SSH settings.

[image: Azure Devops Server Management Console]